# Javascript - object properties not transferring

Tags: javascript, ajax, javascript-objects

I am pretty new to Javascript and cannot for my life figure out why the following object properties are not transferring.

I am calling the object as follows:

```
var URL = "TABLE=_Products&COLUMNS=price_Qty,Sale&MATCH=internal_Model&ROWS="+itemnum ;
var ITEM = new get_Database_Info(URL) ;
```

and the get_Database_Info is:

```
function get_Database_Info(PARAMS) {
    alert(toString(this));
    var URL = document.location.protocol+'//'+document.location.host+'/Catalog/Tools/ajax_Database_Request.php' ;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

    if(!xmlhttp){alert('Error: Cannot send XML request.');}
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                alert(toString(this));
                var RESPONSE = xmlhttp.responseText ;
                RESPONSE = RESPONSE.replace(/^\s+/, '');
                var ARR = RESPONSE.split('||') ;
                ARR.pop() ;
                for(var i=0; i<ARR.length; i++){
                    var temparr1 = ARR[i].split('=') ;
                    var NUM = temparr1[0] ;
                    this[NUM] = new Array() ;
                        var temparr2 =   temparr1[1].split('/|') ;
                        temparr2.shift() ;
                            for(var x=0; x<temparr2.length; x++){

                                var temparr3 = temparr2[x].split('??') ;

                                this[NUM][temparr3[0]] = temparr3[1] ;

                            }
                }

            }
        }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", URL, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", PARAMS.length);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlhttp.send(PARAMS);
```

}

I have verified that all the properties are in 'this' within the scope of get_Database_Info but they are not transferring back to ITEM.

Comment: The problem was calling an asynchronous request. I see how that works now TYVM to all the posters. Strange though that the specific script continues to run even though i virtually demanded that the object get those properties first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When are you checking the contents of the object? The request is asynchronous, so you have to wait until the callback has processed the response before there are any properties in the object.

If you look for the properties immediately after the object is created, they will never be there. Even if the response is really quick, the first time that the callback can run is when you exit the function where you created the object, so the browser gets the control back.

Answer (score 0):

I would venture to guess that the when the function that is attached to onreadystatechange runs that `this` is no longer attached to the object that is being created in the constructor but is probably attached to the global object or the `xmlhttp` object. I would try using the `var that=this` pattern:

```
function get_Database_Info(PARAMS) {
    alert(toString(this));
    var URL = document.location.protocol+'//'+document.location.host+'/Catalog/Tools/ajax_Database_Request.php' ;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

    var that=this; // value of that will be stored in the closure

    if(!xmlhttp){alert('Error: Cannot send XML request.');}
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                alert(toString(that));
                var RESPONSE = xmlhttp.responseText ;
                RESPONSE = RESPONSE.replace(/^\s+/, '');
                var ARR = RESPONSE.split('||') ;
                ARR.pop();
                var arrLength = ARR.length; // always precompute array length
                for(var i=0; i<ARR.length; i++){
                    var temparr1 = ARR[i].split('=') ;
                    var NUM = temparr1[0] ;
                    // that is actually equal to the object that I created
                    // in the constructor.
                    that[NUM] = new Array() ;
                    var temparr2 =   temparr1[1].split('/|') ;
                    temparr2.shift() ;
                    var arrayLength = temparr2.length; // always precompute length
                    for(var x=0; x<arrayLength; x++){
                        var temparr3 = temparr2[x].split('??') ;
                        that[NUM][temparr3[0]] = temparr3[1] ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", URL, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", PARAMS.length);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlhttp.send(PARAMS);
```

Also, as noted in the comments, when you are iterating over the values in an array for a `for` loop, you should not use array.length directly, as the `length` method will be called every time through the loop, adding a great deal of unnecessary work.

Also, as @Guffa notes, the function that adds the values is called asynchronously, so the properties will not exist until the XmlHttpRequest has completed, and that is a very dangerous anti-pattern. I would strongly advise against it. It's better to have your constructor make a synchronous request for the data.